# How to automate the task of resizing text layer according to the data entered in Photoshop from Tkinter and to place an image where text ends?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, photoshop-script, tkinter-text

I made a GUI Application that takes user input and adds that to a CSV as well as a Photoshop file and renders it. This is what it looks like:

[image: Focus on the "R" column]

Focus on the "R" text field. see where it ends. The R text field will have variable length of data. As soon as it ends, I want to add an image at the bottom right where it ends. Right now the image just sits at the bottom right of the PSD document like this:

[image: Look where Image is placed]

And here is how I want it to be placed. Right after the last line of the text...

[image: I want it to be automatically placed right here.]

And I know it can be done manually very easily but my client does not want to open Photoshop at all or do any adjustments.

Here is the part of the code that deals with the R Text widget:

```
R=Label(contentLF,font="Arial 20",text="R:", bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=4,column=1, sticky=E)
eR=Text(contentLF, font="Arial 10", width=90, height=12)
eR.grid(row=4, column=2, pady=10)
```

Here is the code that deals with taking the data from the Text widget and entering it into the PSD file:

```
k=eR.get()
lf9 = doc.ArtLayers["R"]
tol9 = lf9.TextItem
k=k.rstrip("\n")
k=k.replace("\n","\r")
tol9.contents = k
```

Comment: You need to add a [mre] to your question.

Comment: As you can see from my karma, I am new to Stack Overflow. Please forgive me, I will repost the question properly

Comment: You may find this interesting if client doesn't want to pay Adobe every month for the rest of his life... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52115925/2836621

Comment: Alright, will look into it, thank you! :)

Comment: But how do I find out the exacu coordinates in pixels of the place holders in my template? Also, is it even possible to pass entire paragraphs as an argument into the writer function?

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I find out the exact coordinates in pixels of the place
> holders in my template?

In Photoshop, the position (and indirectly) the size of a layer is determined by its bounds property.

If you need to know where your text will end, you need to look at its bottom bounds.

In your case, it would be something like (Javascript):

```
var textBottomBounds = tol9.bounds[3].value;
```

To place your image at that location, you will need to perform a "translation", which is Photoshop language for moving an object on canvas. The *translate* function does not take precise coordinates, but delta ones - meaning that you need to calculate the distance between your image's current position (bounds) and your desired coordinates.

We know that the image should be at the end of text vertically, but horizontally, it's up to you. You can either calculate it (like 2/3 of canvas width) or you can simply not move the image horizontally at all, in which case your deltaX will be zero.

```
var imageDeltaY = textBottomBounds - myImageLayer.bounds[1].value;

//move image
myImageLayer.translate(0, imageDeltaY);
```

FYI:

```
/**** BOUNDS ARRAY REFERENCE: ****/

//An array of 4 values in the order [x1,y1,x2,y2] or [Left,Top,Right,Bottom]  
    
// bounds[0] = x1 or Left
// bounds[1] = y1 or Top
// bounds[2] = x2 or Right
// bounds[3] = y2 or Bottom

//    Bounds:
//    + - - - - - - - [1] - - - - - - - +
//    |                                 |
//    |                                 |
//   [0]                               [2]
//    |                                 |
//    |                                 |
//    + - - - - - - - [3] - - - - - - - +
```

Hope this helps someone.